# How to recode ordinal variable?

Tags: r, recode

I am using survey data from the World Values Survey, I used the code below to change my variable from a numeric to an ordered variable

```
renameddata$Education= ordered(renameddata$Education, levels =c(-2,-1,840001,840002,840003,
                                         840004,840005,840006,840007,
                                         840008,840009),
        labels = c("NA","NA","LessHighSchool","SomeHighSchool",
                   "GED","SomeCollege","Associates","Bachelors",
                   "Masters","Professional","Doctorate"))
```

However, now I want to recode the education variable so that `LessHighSchool` and `SomeHighSchool` become one e.g `"NO GED"`, and so that `SomeCollege`, `Associates` and `Bachelors` become `"Undergraduate"` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want to recode the created factor variable, you can use `fct_collapse` from the `forcats` package:

**Input:**

```
renameddata <- data.frame(Education = c(-2, -1, 840001, 840002, 840003, 840004, 840005, 840006, 840007, 840008, 840009))

renameddata$Education = ordered(renameddata$Education,
                                levels = c(-2, -1, 840001, 840002, 840003, 840004, 840005, 840006, 840007, 840008, 840009),
                                labels = c("NA", "NA", "LessHighSchool", "SomeHighSchool", "GED", "SomeCollege", "Associates", "Bachelors", "Masters", "Professional", "Doctorate"))
```

**Recoding:**

```
library(forcats)
renameddata$Education <- fct_collapse(renameddata$Education,
                                      "NO GED" = c("LessHighSchool", "SomeHighSchool"),
                                      "Undergraduate" = c("SomeCollege", "Associates", "Bachelors"))
```

gives:

```
       Education
1             NA
2             NA
3         NO GED
4         NO GED
5            GED
6  Undergraduate
7  Undergraduate
8  Undergraduate
9        Masters
10  Professional
11     Doctorate
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
library(dplyr)
renameddat <- renameddat %>% mutate(Education = 
        case_when(
          Education %in% c(840001,840002) ~ "No GED", 
          Education == 840003 ~ "GED", 
          Education %in% c(840004,840005,840006) ~ "Undergraduate", 
          Education %in% c(840007,840008,840009) ~ "Graduate", 
      TRUE ~ NA_character_), 
Education=factor(Education, 
                 levels=c("No GED", "GED", "Undergraduate", "Graduate")))
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, however I am encountering a problem when I run the code, it reads

Comment: Error: unexpected ')' in:
"Education=factor(Education, 
                 levels=c("No GED", "GED", "Undergraduate", "Graduate")))"
>                                         Education %in% c(840001,840002) ~ "No GED", 
Error: unexpected ',' in "                                        Education %in% c(840001,840002) ~ "No GED","
>                                         Education == 840003 ~ "GED",

Comment: @Varuna99 Sorry, misplaced parenthesis. I edited the answer so it should work now.